# Please recommend a simple a way to create a bipolar single value indicator gauge using pure python, or a python library

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to use a visual single value indicator to display a value calculated by my python script.

Ideally I would like to use pure python or a python library to achieve this goal. (My knowledge is limited to python, HTML and CSS along with very minimal Javascript.)

The value I would like to be displayed is dynamically changes and so should the gauge/indicator.

Ideally the indicator should be rendered locally or in the web-browser.

My initial idea was to use Plotly to render the graph, then dash to dynamically display it via a web-browser. (unfortunately that is not possible as Plotly does not have the type of indicator I would like to use. The value calculated by the script is sometimes negative.)

I would like to use something like this:
[image]

Could you please point me to the right directions as to how could I achieve this goal?

Comment: Surely the entire dial is just a static image, onto which can draw an orange triangle for the needle and do some text in an LCD-like font. Should be easy with PIL/Pillow.

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/gauge-charts/ try this

Comment: @Vitaliy Korolyk What you recommended was the first place I looked at, but unfortunately that Plotly gauge can not display negative values and the gauge indicator can not start from zero.

Comment: Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. We require a **specific** question; we cannot design an entire program feature for you. Think about the logical steps need to solve the problem, and figure out where you are stuck. For example: can you write code that draws something, at all? Can you write code that uses the value in order to change what is drawn? Do you have a plan in mind for what should be drawn, according to the value? More importantly, **what are your requirements**? Are you just going to save an image file? Update a GUI in real time? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot design can be changed as you like.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

value = -10

fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
    mode="number+gauge", value=value,
    domain={'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
    title={'text': "Temperature", 'font': {"size": 24}},
    gauge={
        'shape': "angular",
        'axis': {'range': [-50, 50]},
        'bgcolor': "white",
        'bar': {'color': "darkblue", 'thickness': 0},
        'steps': [
            {'range': [-50, 0], 'color': "cyan", 'thickness': 1},
            {'range': [0, 50], 'color': "royalblue", 'thickness': 1},
            {'range': [0, value], 'color': "yellow", 'thickness': 0.75}]}
))

fig.update_layout(height=1000)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that this was possible! Would you recommend using dash, or something else instead to make this dynamic?

Comment: dash recommended